# How to make RegionPlot for lists of points

Tags: plotting

Suppose I have the following function:

```
DC[x_, y_] := 3 x - y
sigma[x_, y_, z_, d_] := 3 DC[x, y] + 5 z + d
```

I made list of `sigma[x, y, 3, 3]` versus `x` with a condition on `DC[x,y]`
by:

```
T = Table[{x, If[-50 < DC[x, y] < 50, sigma[x, y, 2, 3]]}, 
            {x, -5, -2,1},{y,2, 6, 1}];
```

Then

`ListPlot[T]` gives:

[image]

The problem, I don't want a graph like the previous one, alternatively, I 'd like to make a graph like:

[image]

`with the area between lines shaded`,i.e., I'd like to plot the region between the maximum and minimum scatter points of the function ..

Like for instance this plot:

[image]

I think I should use from beginning some command rather than ListPlot, like RegionPlot ?

Comment: I suppose adding Filling->{1->{2}} can make this graphics better in style? @ss

Comment: In your latter case, Filling->Axis will do the job

Comment: FillingForm can change the properties of your Filling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lines = Sort[#, #1[[2]] < #[[2]] &][[{1, -1}]] & /@ T;
top = lines[[All, 1]];
bot = lines[[All, 2]];
Show[ListPlot[T],
ListLinePlot[{top, bot}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]]
```

[image]

Or you can use `ConvexHullMesh` to get the region where all the points are.

```
Show[ConvexHullMesh[Flatten[T, 1]], ListPlot[T],
      AspectRatio -> 0.75, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

**For Mathematica 7**

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"]
T1 = Flatten[T, 1];
ListPlot[T1, Prolog -> {Opacity[0.3], Blue, Polygon[T1[[#]] & /@ ConvexHull[T1]]}]
```

Comment: Actually from the beginning can I use some command instead of ListPlot, because I don't want these points. Rather I want to make "shaded" region

Comment: use `Filling`. I modified my answer.

Comment: I'm also modified my question, please look at ..

Comment: You can not use `RegionPlot` here, because it is not a single function you are plotting. You have multiple parameter value and each will describe one condition.  So you will end up with combining 5 different regions.

Comment: So can I just make a smooth curve a round the scatter points, like the attached blue plot ..

Comment: I think `ConvexHullMesh` would be a good option for you. l added it in my answer.

Comment: Why it doesn’t work for me, it returns an error ..

Comment: I use Mathematica 7 ..

Comment: you need to use  `ComputationalGeometry` package for M7.

Comment: I used << ComputationalGeometry` , but it didn't get it. Even tried M9, for example : `pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {5, 1}];`
`ConvexHullMesh[pts]`, but didn't work as well, it seems I should use M10

Comment: Dis you check the final part of my answer? `ConvexHullMesh[pts]` will work with M10.

Comment: Oh, yes I saw, thanx.

Comment: I tired to vary all variables `T = Table[{x, If[-50 < DC[x, y] < 50, sigma[x, y, z, d]]}, {x, -5, -2,  1}, {y, 2, 6, 1}, {z, 6, 9, 1}, {d, 2, 9, 1}]`. Now `ListPlot[T]` doesn’t make graph nor `ConvexHull`, I think some thing may change in `T1 = Flatten[T, 1];`, but I wonder why ListPlot didn't make the scatter points

Comment: If you are using `n` variable then use `Flatten[T,n-1]`.